# pgbouncer ignores pidfile from ini

Tags: pgbouncer, amazon-linux

trying to start pgbouncer I see in log:

> 2017-04-25 11:18:06.319 7186 FATAL @src/main.c:612 in function
>   check_pidfile(): pidfile exists, another instance running?

indeed, it was not deleted by `service pgbouncer stop`:

```
[root@b ~]# grep pid /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini
pidfile = /pg/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
[root@b ~]# ls -al /pg/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 pgbouncer pgbouncer 5 Apr 25 10:45 /pg/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
```

because it is hard coded in init:

```
[root@b ~]# grep ^pid /etc/init.d/pgbouncer
pidfile=/var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
```

when I change the path to the one I specify in `/etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini` it starts working...

**Qestion**: What do I do to make `init.d` pickup pid file location from config?

I have:

```
[root@b ~]# uname -a
Linux 4.9.20-11.31.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 13 01:53:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@b ~]# pgbouncer -V
pgbouncer version 1.7.2
```

Installed it with:

```
wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-96-9.6-2.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh pgdg-ami201503-96-9.6-2.noarch.rpm
yum install pgbouncer
```

.